# JS: Put elements to array beginning on condition

Tags: javascript

I have an array something like this:

```
[
    {id: 5, attr: 99},
    {id: 7, attr: null},
    {id: 2, attr: 8},
    {id: 9, attr: 3},
    {id: 4, attr: null}
]
```

What would be the most efficient to put all objects with `attr === null` at the beginning of the array, without changing order of other elements in the array? (e.g. I need ids to go in this order: 7, 4, 5, 2, 9 (the order of 7 and 4 don't matter, but the order of 5, 2, 9 must never change.)

Simple fiddle to test your code: http://jsfiddle.net/8GEPC/

Comment: Please comment if I didn't explain something clearly enough.

Comment: Do you really need to have the most efficient way? It probably doesn't matter... Look into [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Efficiency doesn't really matter, I just like making everything as fast as possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = [
    {id: 5, attr: 99},
    {id: 7, attr: null},
    {id: 2, attr: 8},
    {id: 9, attr: 3},
    {id: 4, attr: null}
]

var nulls = arr.filter(function(a){return a.attr === null});
var notnulls = arr.filter(function(a){return a.attr !== null});

nulls.concat(notnulls);

// outputs [{"id":7,"attr":null},{"id":4,"attr":null},{"id":5,"attr":99},{"id":2,"attr":8},{"id":9,"attr":3}]
```

And here's a solution using reduce:

```
var sorted = arr.reduce(function(output, element) {
  if (element.attr === null)
    output.unshift(element);
  else
    output.push(element);
  return output
}, []);
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Just forgot to do arr = arr.reduce. Accepted this for reduce (Sort looks too ugly, sorry)

Answer (score 3):

Could used built in filter methods that require two loops or one while loop to find the elements and remove them.

```
var x = [
    {id: 5, attr: 99},
    {id: 7, attr: null},
    {id: 2, attr: 8},
    {id: 9, attr: 3},
    {id: 4, attr: null}
];

var temp = [];
for(var i = x.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if (x[i].attr===null) {               //if we have a null
        temp.unshift(x.splice(i,1)[0]);   //remove the element from org and add to temp
    }
}
x = temp.concat(x);  //add the original to the temp to maintain the order
```

Comment: This looks like the fastest implementation so far: http://jsperf.com/js-put-elements-to-array-beginning-on-condition/3

Answer (score 1):

Grab the objects where `attr === null`.

```
var withNull = arr.filter(function (el) { return el.attr === null });
```

Grab the objects where `attr !== null`.

```
var withVal = arr.filter(function (el) { return el.attr !== null });
```

Add the 'null array' to the front of the 'values array'.

```
withVal.unshift.apply(withVal, withNull);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VU9n7/11/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function customSort(myArray) {
  var result = [];
  myArray.map(function(el, idx, arr) {
    return myArray[idx].attr === null ? result.unshift(myArray[idx]) : result.push(myArray[idx]);
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(customSort([
    {id: 5, attr: 99},
    {id: 7, attr: null},
    {id: 2, attr: 8},
    {id: 9, attr: 3},
    {id: 4, attr: null}
]));
```